# FastAPI - How to render Jinja2 template with variable that contains special characters?

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2, fastapi

I'm trying to render this Jinja2 template:

```py
@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def read_root(request: Request, item: Optional[str] = None):
    item = "<script>"
    return templates.TemplateResponse('index.html', {
     'request': request,
     'item': item
    })
```

but when I use the variable in the HTML template, for example:

```
<h1>{{item}}</h1>
```

it shows this in the code:

```
<h1>&lt;script&gt;</h1>
```

is there anyway to decode that variable to show as it is declared?

Comment: where have you declared `templates` ? what does it look like?

Comment: `app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")`

Answer (score 2):

Just found out how to do it,

adding in the HTML:

```
{% autoescape false %}
{{ your_variable }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: This is very cool! I was reading blocks of HTML from text files for insertion into templates and all the html tags were getting mangled like you showed. Your fix worked like magic. Thanks for sharing, bro!

Answer (score 1):

FastAPI uses the templating support in [starlette](https://www.starlette.io/templates/), which sets the Jinja2 [autoescape](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#high-level-api) option by default.

You can disable that like this:

```
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
templates.env.autoescape = False
```

With more recent versions of `starlette`, you may also be able to do this:

```
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates", autoescape=False)
```

...but with the version I'm running the latter option fails. The former option should work in any case.

Comment: thank you  for your reply, but unfortunately did't work any of those:  apparently those are not allowed . This is how I declare the templates:       ` app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates") `

Comment: You should be able to set `templates.env.autoescape = False`, then. What does "didn't work" mean? Did you get an error message? What was it?

Comment: it's weird, when I use this, the sentence appears in red in visual studio, like the ´template.env´ doesn't have the property ´.autoescape´

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to wrap the markup you consider safe to render in `markupsafe.Markup`.